# Simultaneous calls to WCFService hosted in Azure fails

Tags: entity-framework, azure, wcf, simultaneous

I have a WCFService hosted in Microsoft Azure Cloud Services. The client machine can successfully make calls to the WCFServices one at a time. When I run tests with my client machine to simultaneously call the webservice, one one client can make a successful call and rest all of them fail.

I thought this scenario should be automatically handled. Do I have to make special configuration changes to make simultaneous call work?

I have exceptions like :

1] ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

2] "Calling \'Read\' when the data reader is closed is not a valid operation."

I am using EntityFramework for my data layer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what the calls do and how long after do they fail?  Calling WCF service multiple times at the same time is absolutely supported by Azure.  However, if your calls run into contention between one another and are blocking one another, all but one may fail.

If one of your calls makes the other calls take longer than 1 min to complete, then Azure's load balancer will kill the other calls.  Each call is allowed to complete for 1 min, as I painfully found out recently.

Comment: Well, the call returns a list which is very small in size. The call takes less than 2 seconds. But the subequent calls fail immediately.

Comment: Do you have the concurrency and instance settings of WCF set correctly?

Comment: Taylor, How do I do that? can you point me to an appropriate msdn document?

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problem. I am calling this from Windows Service, during that time it is not working. Rest of all other calls it is working well